# How to use recursion to add the product of two Integers together?

Tags: ada

In this code, I am asking the user to input two integers (`Index`, `Mindex`) and then I display all the integers between `1..Index` and `1..Mindex`. What my problem is here that I do not know how to multiply the values of `Integers` in `Index` and `Integers` in `Mindex and then add up the product of these two together

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Add is
   Index, Mindex : Integer;

   procedure calc (Item : in Integer) is
      New_Value : Integer;
   begin
      Put ("The value of the index is now");
      Put (Item);
      New_Line;
      New_Value := (Item - 1);
      if New_Value > 0 then
         calc (New_Value);
      end if;
   end calc;
begin
   Get (Index);
   Get (Mindex);
   calc (Index);
   New_Line;
   calc (Mindex);
end Add;
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or some other [recursive multiplication algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=recursive+multiplication+algorithm&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: Just a simple recursion. Ex: when the user writes 4 and 3, then my code should display the product of this integer which is  4*3*2*1 = 24   and 3*2*1=6 and then add these two integers (24 + 6) together

Comment: If you are looking for a [recursive factorial algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=recursive+factorial+algorithm&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), please [edit] your question to clarify and update your [mcve] to show your chosen approach.

Comment: Just use a recursive function to calculate each factorial, and then just add the two results.

Comment: And how do I write a recursive function that calculates each factorial? I need a recursive formula for that.

Comment: Can you see the recursion by just looking at it? Then think : given Fact(N-1), how would you calculate Fact(N)? Do you know the value of Fact(1)?

Answer (score 1):

A factorial keeps chaining multiplication with each decreasing value:  5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120.  In order to do the recursion, you'll need to have two cases inside your recursive function:  If your value is above 1, then multiply that value with the next smallest number.  That's the recursive part where you will call Factorial(N-1) inside of Factorial(N).  Otherwise just return 1 (factorial of 0 is 1 mathematically, so both 1! and 0! equal 1).

The way this works in Ada is:

```ada
function Factorial(Value : Natural) return Natural is
begin
    if Value > 1 then
        -- Keep chaining the multiplication with recursion
        return Value * Factorial(Value - 1);
    else
        -- No need to chain as the result is always 1
        return 1;
    end if;
end Factorial;
```

You can then call that Factorial function on each of your numbers and add the results.